# How to make an object destructible?

Tags: unity, 3d, blender

I have some 3d models that I have downloaded from Unity asset store. Most of the time, these objects are not "separatable" so I can't apply a destructible effect.

Is there a way to separate a model into small pieces, whether by using Blender, or a Unity script, or something else?

Comment: hm possible drive-by downvoting. I don't see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: @jhocking It is mainly a blender issue. The mesh needs to be decomposed into smaller chunks. It's not so much dev related as it is art related. There are solutions to his problem that can be solved in Unity ( check Byte56's comment ) but the question in and of itself is a art/modeling problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want the separate pieces to look like. If you mean destroy into recognizable chunks, that requires a lot of complex art work. Technically that can be done in Blender, but frankly that's harder than modeling the things in the first place.

However you may also get the effect you want by shattering the mesh into separate polygons. In that case, there are ways to accomplish that through scripting. Just search the Asset Store for ["destroy mesh script"](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=destroy&mesh&script) to see several options.

Comment: Or just using a particle emitter with various small "chunks", some light and sound.